# create expandable tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, expandablelistview

I'm using API (which one I cannot share publicly), and get responses like

```
[
Response1.response(category1: "cat1", response: "parent0"),
Response1.response(category2: "cat2", response: "parent1"),
Response1.response(category3: "cat3", response: "parent2"),
Response1.response(category4: "cat4", response: "parent3")
]
```

and

```
[
Response2.response(subcategory1: "resp0", response: "child0parent0"),
Response2.response(subcategory2: "resp1", response: "child0parent1"),
Response2.response(subcategory3: "resp2", response: "child0parent2"),
Response2.response(subcategory4: "resp3", response: "child0parent3")
]
```

I want to show data on expandable tableview like below example image or let me know, how can I create 2D array from above two responses?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 3 - Expandable Table View Cells with first cell already expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930856/swift-3-expandable-table-view-cells-with-first-cell-already-expanded)

Comment: @ Enea Dume
No,
I just want to create 2D array from my response, so I can use it in my expandable tableview.
**I want child0parent0,child0parent1,child0parent2,child0parent3 as sub category of parent0 **

Answer (score 1):

Please use this link to get the code for creating expandable tableviews in iOS -
https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Create 2 dimensional array like this -

```
[
"parent 0" : ["child0parent0", "child1parent0", "child2parent0", 
"child3parent0"],
"parent 1" : ["child0parent1", "child1parent1", "child2parent1"],
....
]
```

Comment: so basically for expandable tableview , it's require have two dimensional array.
how can I make two dimensional array from Response1 and Response2?

Comment: how can I make that two dimensional array from Response1 and Response2

Comment: I explained it in the answer pretty simple. If you still need help send me both the responses, I will let you know how to di it.